# Ergodicity in First Passage Percolation in lattice

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, percolation

Consider $\mathbb{Z}^d$ as a graph with edges connecting each $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ with $|x-y|=1$. Let $\tau (e)$ be i.i.d random variables  assigned to each edge $e$. $\tau (e)$ represents the time required to traverse the edge in in either direction. For $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, if $x_0 = x, x_1, \dots, x_n = y$ is a path from $x$ to $y$, the travel time along the path is defined as $\tau(x_0, x_1) +\tau(x_1, x_2) + \cdots + \tau(x_{n-1}, x_n)$. Define the passage time from $x$ to $y$ as $t(x,y)=$ the infimum of the travel times over all paths from $x$ to $y$.

Let $X_{m,n} = t(mu, nu)$, where $u=(1,0,\dots,0)\in \mathbb{Z}^d$.

This seems to be one of the famous examples of applications of the subadditive ergodic theorem. I took the description above from Durrett's [Probability](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) (See Example 6.5.4).

I have no problem understanding why $X_{m,n}$ satisfies conditions of the subadditive ergodic theorem (Liggett's version) except for the following condition, which is critical to show that $X_{0,n}/n$ converges to a constant almost surely.

Condition: $\{X_{nk, (n+1)k}, n\geq 1\}$ is ergodic.

Durrett says it can be reduced to the tail $\sigma$-field of the i.i.d. sequence $\{\tau (e)\}$. I don't see why that is the case. Other literature, such as [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03262.pdf), says the ergodicity follows directly from the fact that $\{\tau (e)\}$ is i.i.d. But, still, it doesn't seem trivial to me.

If $X$ can be reduced to the tail $\sigma$-field of $\{\tau (e)\}$ as Durrett says, $X_{m,n}$ should be determined by a part of $\{\tau(e)\}$. However, it doesn't seem obvious to me.

Any assistance or suggestion would be very much appreciated!

**Self-resolved:**
Realized that you can show that $X= \lim_{n\to \infty}X_{0,n}/n$ is constant by showing $X$ is measurable with respect to the tail $\sigma$-field of $\{\tau(e)\}$ instead of showing ergodicity of the sequence $\{X_{nk, (n+1)k}, k\geq 1\}$.

Comment: Added my thought process in the end to clarify where I'm struggling.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing implies ergodicity. Write $Y_n=X_{nk, (n+1)k}$. To verify mixing, we need to show that for each fixed $\ell$, and indicator functions $f,g$, of $\ell$ variables,
$f(\{Y_n: n \le \ell\})$ is asymptotically independent (as $N \to \infty$) from $g(\{Y_n: N  \le  n \le N+\ell\})$ and this follows from the mixing property of the underlying $\{\tau(e)\}$. Recall the latter is proved by approximating every event by a cylinder event that only depends on a finite number of $\tau(e)$.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! However, the mixing property is a new concept to me, so it may take me some time to comprehend your answer. Neither of the references I cited touches on the mixing property. So I expect there is a way to explain this without using such a concept.

Comment: The concept is worth knowing.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the connection between $X$ and $\tau$?

Comment: $Y_n$ is an infimum over all paths between two specific points. It is well approximated by an infimum over a large bounded region.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. Could you elaborate on how you approximate $X_{m, n}$? Also, could you suggest a reference that contains all the knowledge necessary to understand this?

Comment: Start by understanding why an i.i.d. sequence is ergodic under the shift. You can find this in Durrett's book and many other sources. One proof goes via mixing, another via a direct approximation by cylinder events. Then try to adapt that proof to the case you are examining, and you will get a variant of the argument above.